# Put spaces in between some of of the characters

Tags: java, string, replace, operators

I want to put spaces only after and before of an mathematical operator:

for example:

55/2*456-5+5

result:
55 / 2 * 456 - 5 + 5

Comment: Any efforts so far ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

one way to do this:

```
String lEquation = "55/2*456-5+5";
lEquation = lEquation.replaceAll("\\/"," \\/ ").replaceAll("\\*"," \\* ").replaceAll("-"," - ").replaceAll("\\+"," \\+ ");
System.out.println("My equation: "+ lEquation);
```

result will be:

```
My equation: 55 / 2 * 456 - 5 + 5
```